How to create a dropdown which contains Tkinter frames?
I want to create a similar UI to the Windows update UI which contains dropdowns. Each dropdown can be expanded to reveal additional tkinter frames with buttons on the right:

How can I make this UI in tkinter? I tried looking into dropdowns in tkinter but there isn't an easy way to insert other elements besides the very basic text elements.

It's called an expandable frame and has an answer in the linked question.

As suggested, there is no direct way to do what you want. You will have to create the dropdown yourself using various widgets.
